# Getting error when trying to upload war file in Nexus by using Nexus artifactory uploader

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, repository, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Getting error like java.lang.null pointer exception while doing Jenkins pipeline job project by using Nexus artifactory uploader and it was working for free style project and it was showing as hudson.security issue [here was the error shown in below image please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxcUq.jpg)

Iam expecting to resolve the issue